# ASP.NET MVC 3 - File upload through AngularJS

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, file-upload, angularjs

I'm using [AngularJS](http://angularjs.org/) with my pages, and I have a doubt: when I do post with my form, how can I pass some selected file to my ASP.NET MVC 3 Controller?
Check this out:

My form:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" ng-controller="FilesController" ng-submit="submitingForm()">
    <div>
        Choose the file:
        <input type="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().setSelectedFile(this)" />
    </div>

    <input type="submit" value="Confirm" />
</form>
```

And the AngularJS Controller:

```
var module = angular.module('application', []);

(function (ang, app) {

    function FilesController($scope, $http) {

        $scope.setSelectedFile = function (element) {
            $scope.$apply(function($scope) {
                $scope.selectedFile = element.files[0];
            });
        };

        $scope.submitingForm = function() {

            $http.post(url, ???????).success(function() {
                // How to pass that selected file for my ASP.NET controller?
            });
        }
    }

    app.controller("FilesController", FilesController);
})(angular, module);
```

Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not quite familiar with AngularJS but if you are attempting to upload a file using an AJAX request you can forget about it. That's not something that could be done. You could use the [`HTML5 File API`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications) if you want to upload files asynchronously to the server. There's an [`entire section`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Using_files_from_web_applications#Example.3A_Uploading_a_user-selected_file) dedicated to this.

And if your client browsers do not support the HTML5 File API you could use a File Upload plugin such as [`FineUploader`](http://fineuploader.com/) or [`Uploadify`](http://www.uploadify.com/) (there are quite many others, just google).

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying to use these plugins, and I've got a pretty success!

Comment: "you are attempting to upload a file using an AJAX request you can forget about it", I just did it though in MVC4 with angular, using this https://github.com/danialfarid/angular-file-upload

Answer (score 1):

My Approach is to use [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData).

Create a input tag like this.

```
<input id="imgInp" type="file" aria-label="Add photos to your post" class="upload" name="file" onchange="angular.element(this).scope().LoadFileData(this.files)" multiple="" accept="image/*" style="margin-top: -38px; opacity: 0; width: 28px;">
```

And in your Angular Controller create a method `LoadFileData(inputFiles)` as bellow:

```
 var formData = new FormData();

 $scope.LoadFileData = function (files) {
        for (var file in files) {
            formData.append("file", files[file]);
        }
    };
```

Now in formData variable you will have the uploaded files. Just send it to asp.net mvc controller.

```
$scope.submit = function () {
        $http.post("/YourController/Method", formData, {
            withCredentials: true,
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
            transformRequest: angular.identity
        }).success(function (response) {
      }
```

In Server side, Asp.NET MVC 4 controller you will have the files

```
var files = Request.Files;
```

Comment: Welcome @user3814490. FormData is really good approach to upload file.

Comment: Yes it is and I saved in database as well as binary array.