# How to send email attachment without using httppostedfilebase in c#?

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, email-attachments

I used angularjs to submit a form via ajax to call the action in my mvc controller. and
using my angular directives I can get the filename, contenttype and contentlength of the selected file. Are this three information that I extracted from angular  are enough to attach the file to my email? Thank you all for your help.

Comment: Apart from @J-D's answer being the correct answer, please explain the actual problem you're trying to solve, because this smells like an XY problem. It is probably something like _"I want my site's visitors to be able to send large files per email, but I don't want to wait for the upload"_. Then your actual problem is that email is not the proper medium to send large files.

Comment: Basically I have an online application form that user can attached their CV's. I've use modal form to fill up the name field, email field etc.. upon submitting the form I use angular to get the the information and pass those information to mvc action controller through ajax call. I didn't use HttpPostedFileBase in this case. Using directive I can get the filename, type and contentlength.

Comment: You can't do anything with that. You need to upload the file.

Comment: Are you saying that HttpPostedFileBase is the only way to attach a file to email?

Comment: No, I'm saying that in order to attach a file from the client to a mail you send from the server, you have to upload that file from the client to the server. HttpPostedFileBase is one of the ways to upload files. See also [ASP.NET MVC 3 - File upload through AngularJS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14277423/asp-net-mvc-3-file-upload-through-angularjs).

Answer (score 1):

> I can get the filename, contenttype and contentlength of the selected
>   file.

No that's not enough to send files as a attachment to the mail. Without the **content** of the file all of the above mentioned detailed are of no value.

**EDIT** : If you are planning to post HttpPostedFileBase in your mvc controller then you can extract the above details as below.

To get extension:

```
string extension = Path.GetExtension(upload.FileName);
```

where upload is of type HttpPostedFileBase.

To get file name :

```
string fileName = Path.GetFileName(upload.FileName);
```

To get file type:

```
string contentType = upload.ContentType
```

Comment: I tried to pass these three information to httppostedfilebase but it says read only. Is there a way that I can convert it to match the httppostedfilebase? I'v been googling and scratching my head since last night. Thanks for your input.

Comment: Why you need to pass these information when they are already available in it. Have a look at this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httppostedfilebase(v=vs.110).aspx. So when you post a file it will automatically assign this fields to HttpPostedFileBase class and you can read same from your c# code

Comment: I cannot use HttpPostedFileBase because whenever I use it using ajax.post it always return null. If I'm going to use the normal Html.Begin form its fine but the draw back is the postback. By the I'm using modal to submit the form via ajax.post.

Comment: here's the angularjs directive I use to get the input file properties. http://jsfiddle.net/spyboost/97WLP/light/